# Ignoring files that have already existed with git

Tags: git, gitignore

If I have a repo with files that were previously not in my `.gitignore` file that I now want to ignore, how do I do this without deleting the files locally and when you pull from the repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rm --cached somefile` will preserve the local copy of the file but make git stop tracking that file. Once you do that, you can add the file to `.gitignore` too.

Comment: Yes, but when I pull from the repo the files get deleted.

Comment: Yep, that's unavoidable. Even if you just switch to a different branch and then back the file will be removed.